# Plotting large scale image embeddings

Tags: graphics, image-processing, visualization, neural-networks, dimension-reduction

I'm looking for help making publication-quality graphics for visualizing 2D embeddings of image datasets, so that they look like this:

[image]

These two-dimensional embeddings of thumbnails (sometimes with magnifying zoom-in's - as shown above in red) are commonly seen plots in ML or computer vision papers, for instance:

- [Learning visual similarity for product design with convolutional neural networks](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kb/publications/SIG15ProductNet.pdf)
- [Multi-Modal Embedding for Main Product Detection in Fashion](http://www.iri.upc.edu/files/scidoc/1938-Multi-Modal-Embedding-for-Main-Product-Detection-in-Fashion.pdf)
- [Learning Type-Aware Embeddings for Fashion Compatibility](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09196)

*This is typically done to show that a neural network learns a function that maps input images to a latent space such that the l2-norm in that space approximated the semantic distance in the input space.*

After learning some latent embedding space and using `DimensionReduce` (with the [TSNE](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) method) you have one (x,y) point for each image, these are then *otherwise masaged into a nice disk*. I think this is how it's done:

1. Images are conformed (maybe aspect ratio preserving crops?)
2. The (x,y) points are snapped to some chosen disc-shaped grid (based on step 1)
3. Overlapping photos are somehow dealt with (randomly perhaps or keeping ones with similar entropy)
4. Larger versions of the images are shown for selected areas in rectangular magnifying-glass callouts

Here's another nice example:

[image]

**Example data and code**

To get you started, here's the typical input to this problem - a few thousand images and their embedding coordinates:

```
xy = CloudGet @ CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-6795023f-6362-45bf-9097-de07f37f89a1/embedding-example-xy"];
thumbs = CloudGet @ CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-6795023f-6362-45bf-9097-de07f37f89a1/embedding-example-thumbs"];
Length /@ {xy, thumbs}
MapThread[Labeled, {thumbs[[;; 5]], xy[[;; 5]]}]
```

[image]

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 data = MapThread[
   Inset[#1, #2, Automatic, Scaled[.02]] &, {thumbs, xy}];
 g = Graphics[data, ImageSize -> Full]]
```

[image]

So this doesn't look good yet, and if you zoom in you can see unwanted overlaps:

[image]

It requires the 4 steps above, e.g. to conform the images, massage the blob into a centered grid shape with minimal margins, and magnified with callouts and exported to PDF.

**Possible solutions:**

- Using `WordCloud` to pack them?
- Using `ExternalFunction` with some python libraries?

Comment: In your desired picture, it looks like all the little pictures have exactly the same dimensions, and so are easy to pack regularly (that's why 25 pictures fit in every red box). In your example data set, the pictures have many different sizes and so cannot be packed regularly.

Comment: Right, would be nice to handle the general case, but please feel free to center crop/pad them if you want to simplify it.

Comment: @bills I think you are right, I updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

The first step in imitating the desired pictures is to plot everything on a grid. This can be done by rounding the positions to integer locations:

```
data = MapThread[Inset[#1, #2, Automatic, Scaled[.02]] &, {thumbs, 5 Round[xy]}];
g = Graphics[data, ImageSize -> 900]
```

[image]

Now you can pick out a subset of the images using something like:

```
sel = Select[data[[All]], 0 < #[[2, 1]] < 25 && 10 < #[[2, 2]] < 35 &];
Graphics[sel /. {0.02 -> 0.4}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: You picked 5 by hand? It might be better if somehow the points were slightly rearranged and compressed into a disc though... I think the overlaying callout magnifications are the tricky part

Comment: I just picked it so that it seemed to look OK. You can apply any function you wish instead of the 5*Round.

Comment: if you can put more work into your solution, compressing the space and adding the overlays I’ll accept